# How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless, drivers, atheros, wireshark, packet-analyzer

Hi I am new to Ubuntu and Linux. As I am developing a WiFi product, I want to capture the WiFi traffic wirelessly with Wireshark. Having some searching in the web, I know that I can do that with a USB WiFi adapter and Ubuntu. Then I can run the Wireshark in real monitor/promiscuous mode.

Ok so I bought a TP-Link TP-WN722NC (I want to buy the TP-WN722N at first, but the store only has this model). Also I found a laptop and installed the Ubuntu 14.04.1. Then I noticed that I need a driver for this adaptor. So I try to follow the blog post [Installing TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 11.10](http://blog.y3xz.com/blog/2011/10/23/installing-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-1110/) to install the driver *ath9k_htc* but seems it was not successful.

Then I downloaded the backports 3.16-1 by running these two commands:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.16/backports-3.16-1.tar.gz
tar xvf compat-wireless-2.6.38.2-2.tar.bz2
```

However, after that point do not know what should I do. Could you help guide me to install the correct driver?

Comment: Boy this looks terrible, after viewing the answer, I think I'll swap to a different USB wireless receiver vendor ;( does it really have to touch grub for any good reason?!?

Comment: Well I just unboxed my TL-WN772N plugged, plugged it into my Ubuntu 14.04.1 and it simply worked out of the box...

Comment: I think recent kernel versions (at least since 3.16) have the ath9k driver built-in, so it should just be plug-n-play. Check your kernel version with `uname -r`. **EDIT**: yup, ath9k is built-in since Linux 2.6.35, according to the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc).

Comment: Got my TL-WN772N today, it "just worked" after `sudo aptitude install firmware-atheros`, plugging the device in again, followed by `sudo service network-manager restart` :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Part One**

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

First, you will need to install a few applications to build and compile from source:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Save any unsaved work and reboot. When you sign back in, open a terminal.

---

**Part Two**

Download the needed file:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
```

Now, unzip the tar.gz file:

```
tar xvfz backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
```

Then, **c** hange your **d** irectory to the uncompressed file:

```
cd backports-4.4.2-1
```

Because there is a Makefile, we will be using the `make` command. First, clean the build area by typing this command:

```
sudo make clean
```

Then, use this command to build and compile:

```
sudo make
```

You should receive an error and some instructions. Following these instructions to specify the driver you want to build and install by running the following command:

```
sudo make defconfig-ath9k
```

Now, run make again:

```
sudo make
```

This time you should receive no errors. This may take some time to finish. When it is done, install the driver with the following command:

```
sudo make install
```

You will see some messages saying something about a key. These errors can safely be ignored and should not impact the overall outcome.

---

**Part Three**

Now, run these two commands in an open terminal to load the driver modules at boot time.

```
echo "ath9k" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules

echo "ath9k_htc" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

For the next command, I will use `gedit` as the text editor but you can use nano, leafpad, kate, mousepad or any text editor.

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Now, we need to insert the following two lines before **"exit 0"** so the last four lines of the file should look exactly like this:

```
# Declare TP-WN727N USB ID to ath9k_htc module
echo "148F 7601" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id

exit 0
```

Click on save before exiting out of gedit.

---

**Part Four**

Finally, the script mentions something about updating your initramfs. It might not be needed but these are kernel modules so that's what we will do by running the following command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

and don't forget to update grub when you are done:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Save any unsaved work, leave the device plugged in and reboot for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation, but after finished all the above step. I still cannot see the WiFi connection at the top right corner. At part three, is that I just need to run these two command in the terminal? `echo "ath9k" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`
 `echo "ath9k_htc" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`

Comment: Yes, those two lines are individual commands. The first command is: `echo "ath9k" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` The second command is: `echo "ath9k_htc" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`   You won't have wireless until you're completely done and after you reboot.

Comment: The adaptor is working now! It did not work before because I plugged in the TL-WN727N, which is not using the ath9k driver. One interesting thing is that I can switch on/off the wifi adaptor by the built-in WiFi enable switch at the laptop! I don't know if it is normal, but anyway it works now. Thank you very much :) Btw could you suggest a driver which work for the TL-WN727N in my another post?

Comment: what does this command do ? `apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r` kernel is already installed right ?

Comment: not necessarily, what if you are using low-latency? if you are using the generic kernel the command just cancels out but if not then it should install the headers for the kernel you are using.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds that installs the kernel header files for your kernel, part of the kernel source required to compile drivers

Comment: What tar file are you talking about in step 2?

Comment: @TomášZato Run following command first to download the fileand then run the tar command: `wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.16/backports-3.16-1.tar.gz`

Comment: @TomášZato Also, this may be better because it is more new: http://askubuntu.com/questions/607830/how-to-install-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu

Comment: Do I need to execute command 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' if i use Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I was using Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and `v3.16` did not compile. I followed the same instructions with the latest version from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/ (`v4.4.2` at the time of this post) and it worked; so if you have trouble, maybe try a more recent version too :)

Comment: Note for newer versions of the device: https://askubuntu.com/questions/912498/tl-wn722n-is-not-recognized