# TP-Link TP-WN727N not working on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

I have posted in another thread asking [how to install driver for TL-WN722N](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04). However, as I am really eager to fix the problem sooner and I noticed that someone said Ubuntu has already installed the driver of TL-WN727N, I have just gone to buy a new TL-WN727N. However I still cannot get this adaptor work. Having checked with "lsusb", I can see the device shown in the terminal: "Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp."
I am using the Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Could you help me to get the adaptor work? Thank you

I plug the adaptor into the laptop and then switch on the laptop. Then run sudo iwconfig

Result:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Plug the device in and reboot. Does NetworkManager automatically detect the device? Run the command `sudo iwconfig` to find out. Please post the results

Comment: @mchid The following is the result: 'wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.'

Comment: If the USB device doesn't show up as wlan1 or at all you can try this. Plug in the device and then run these commands: first `sudo modprobe ath9k` next `sudo modprobe ath9k_htc` and finally `echo "148F 7601" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id`

Answer (score 1):

TP Link 727n v1 or v3. Ralink chipsets are rt3070 v1 and rt5370 v3.  The driver is rt2800usb.The version # can be found at the end of the FCC ID: ########V3 located on the back of the device. Also see https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table for more info.
As far as the chart states Mediatek chipsets don't work in permicuous mode or monitor mode.