# no wireless working in latest ubuntu after installation

Tags: wireless

I have dell inspiren 1564 and i have install the latest version on ubuntu today.
the installation is successfully completed in 10+ mins and then i update it.
now everything is working good expect wifi.
i have search on the INTERNET and did some of the solution given in the forums like 
backport i have follow this A-Z
[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and when i put this command in the terminal  its give me

```
    frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

i have try this and get response:

```
    frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
[sudo] password for frank: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

What Should I Do Now ;

i have got this list after pressing this command :

```
    frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ sudo lshw
[sudo] password for frank: 
PCI (sysfs)  
frank-inspiron-1564       
    description: Portable Computer
    product: Inspiron 1564 ()
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: A13
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 ldt16 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=portable frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=disabled
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 08CNC9
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A13
       serial: .       .CN4864302R3387.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 1
          version: A13
          date: 03/29/2011
          size: 122KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 330  @ 2.13GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 5
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: CPU Version
          slot: U2E1
          size: 933MHz
          capacity: 4096MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-through data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-through unified
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-back
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 16
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 3GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: EBJ11UE6BBS0-AE-F
             vendor: AMI
             physical id: 0
             serial: 142E38DD
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M471B5673EH1-CH9
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 634D8D46
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 12
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 12
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:42 memory:f0705800-f070580f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f0706000-f07063ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:f0700000-f0703fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:bc000000-bc1fffff ioport:bc200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:f0400000-f04fffff ioport:bc400000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f0400000-f0403fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:bc600000-bcafffff ioport:f0800000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 02
                serial: b8:ac:6f:51:b9:c6
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:40 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0810000-f0810fff memory:f0800000-f080ffff memory:f0820000-f083ffff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f0706400-f07067ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a6
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:41 ioport:1818(size=8) ioport:180c(size=4) ioport:1810(size=8) ioport:1808(size=4) ioport:1820(size=32) memory:f0705000-f07057ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f0706800-f07068ff ioport:1840(size=32)
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel ips latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0704000-f0704fff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Physical 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.2
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.3
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 0
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SAMSUNG HM250HI
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 2AC1
             serial: S1YKJA0Z215008
             size: 232GiB (250GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000e2c9c
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 3825333c-64bf-414b-a176-a1779caf4134
                size: 230GiB
                capacity: 230GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2014-08-30 17:40:33 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2014-08-31 00:42:37 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2014-08-31 00:42:37 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 2931MiB
                capacity: 2931MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 2931MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD A  DS8A5LH
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 1H68
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-battery
       product: SIMPLO
       vendor: SIMPLO
       physical id: 1
       slot: System Battery Bay
       capacity: 44000mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
  *-remoteaccess UNCLAIMED
       vendor: Intel
       physical id: 2
       capabilities: outbound
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Defined By O.E.M
       product: To Be Defined By O.E.M
       vendor: To Be Defined By O.E.M
       physical id: 3
       version: 2.50
       serial: To Be Defined By O.E.M
       capacity: 32768mWh
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ 
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$
```

**another command and its response :**

```
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb
--2014-08-31 01:51:13--  http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb
Resolving mirrors.kernel.org (mirrors.kernel.org)... 149.20.4.71, 149.20.20.135, 2001:4f8:1:10:0:1994:3:14, ...
Connecting to mirrors.kernel.org (mirrors.kernel.org)|149.20.4.71|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3942580 (3.8M) [application/vnd.debian.binary-package]
Saving to: ‘linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb.1’

100%[=========================================================================================================>] 3,942,580    119KB/s   in 32s    

2014-08-31 01:51:46 (122 KB/s) - ‘linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb.1’ saved [3942580/3942580]

frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
[sudo] password for frank: 
(Reading database ... 193442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware-nonfree (1.14ubuntu1) over (1.14ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-firmware-nonfree (1.14ubuntu1) ...
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$
```

another one :

```
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ dmesg | grep b43
[   14.580479] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_response_rate
[   14.580484] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_response_rate (err -22)
[   14.580605] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_hw
[   14.580606] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_hw (err -22)
[   14.580619] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw
[   14.580621] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw (err -22)
[   14.580633] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_register_hw
[   14.580635] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_register_hw (err -22)
[   14.580646] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name
[   14.580648] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name (err -22)
[   14.580652] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_generic_frame_duration
[   14.580653] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_generic_frame_duration (err -22)
[   14.580657] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queue
[   14.580658] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queue (err -22)
[   14.580681] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_tx_led_name
[   14.580682] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_tx_led_name (err -22)
[   14.580698] b43: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state
[   14.580700] b43: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state (err -22)
[   14.580731] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_rx_led_name
[   14.580732] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_rx_led_name (err -22)
[   14.580751] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_queue_delayed_work
[   14.580752] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_queue_delayed_work (err -22)
[   14.580760] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_ctstoself_get
[   14.580761] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ctstoself_get (err -22)
[   14.580782] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rx
[   14.580784] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx (err -22)
[   14.580802] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queues
[   14.580804] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queues (err -22)
[   14.580809] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_txskb
[   14.580810] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_txskb (err -22)
[   14.580846] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tx_status
[   14.580847] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status (err -22)
[   14.580851] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queue
[   14.580852] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queue (err -22)
[   14.580877] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_assoc_led_name
[   14.580879] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_assoc_led_name (err -22)
[   14.580882] b43: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling
[   14.580884] b43: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling (err -22)
[   14.580906] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
[   14.580907] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
[   14.580913] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
[   14.580914] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
[   14.580931] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rts_get
[   14.580932] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rts_get (err -22)
[   14.580939] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_queue_work
[   14.580940] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_queue_work (err -22)
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ rfkill list
```

**un-Installation of  backports and the follow the chili's instruction and i get this response:**

```
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ dmesg | grep b43
[   14.408606] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[   14.451738] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[   21.432960] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
frank@frank-Inspiron-1564:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: What wireless chip do you have?

Comment: i have update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device requires firmware. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

If you are unable to get the package from the Ubuntu repositories, try:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

And then reboot.

You need to remove the conflicting backports package:

```
cd ~/backports-3.16-1
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot and check the log for errors again:

```
dmesg | grep b43
iwconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a BCM4312.

### Method 1

You may have luck by simply downloading and installing [this DEB file.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) It contains the BCM files. It also is more reliable than the `linux-firmware-nonfree` method as it has less of a chance of breaking other things, such as graphics drivers.

---

### Method 2

1. Download [this file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/b43-fwcutter/1:018-2/+build/5136774/+files/b43-fwcutter_018-2_amd64.deb). It is the B43-FWcutter. Install it using `dpkg -i`.
2. Download [this file](http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2). It contains all of the drivers for your card.
3. Run the following commands in the folder where you downloaded File 2.

   ```
   tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2  
   sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
   ```
4. Reboot
5. ???
6. Profit.

[(src)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access)