# wlan0 not found after installing ath9k from backport - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, backport

I tried installing ath9k from backports looking [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04) for tp-rink wn722nc.

After doing everything I rebooted my computer, but now I don't have wlan0. my internel wifi card is bcm43142 802.11 b/g/n. It's like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558895/how-to-re-enable-wlan0-after-backports-disabled-it).

I had wifi connection before installing ath9k.

`modprobe wl`:

```
   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument)
```

`lshw -c net` :

```
  *-network               

       description: Ethernet interface

       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 08
       serial: 50:af:73:6b:33:f4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:105 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0504000-d0504fff memory:d0500000-d0503fff


 *-network UNCLAIMED


       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0400000-d0407fff
```

lsmod has `ath9k` at its result, but no wl.

My questions are

1. Can network manager support 2 wireless drivers?
2. if not, how do I switch between drivers?
3. where is my `wlan0`?

Please help me find `wlan0`.

Comment: Add the result of `lshw -c net` to your question

Comment: Don't do that with Broadcomm drivers!  Go here instead: [installing broadcom Wireless drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395) and report back.

Comment: _ath9k_ is a driver for an Atheros wireless card, not Broadcom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd backports-3.16-1
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot and if it still doesn't work do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo update-pciids
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Thanks, jeremy31 and kasiya. My wlan is working now. Thanks again!