# Wireless does't work without TP-Link TL-WN722N after I installed

Tags: wireless, drivers

I use Ubuntu 14.04. My wireless works fine until I installed TP-Link TL-WN722N. I used this tutorial to install [How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04)
Now Ubuntu don't see my defauld wireless card. I can use wireless only with TL-WN722N connected.

Edit:

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2` output:

```
net 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: 
Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5] 
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]:
Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23] Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 090c:37b1 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]      Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n     Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2150 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046 Bluetooth Device 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `history | grep backport` to your question along with 'lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: root@Lenovo-G550:~# lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net  
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)  
 Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]  
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)    
 Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23]  
 Kernel driver in use: tg3

Comment: root@Lenovo-G550:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 090c:37b1 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bc2:3320 Seagate RSS LLC SRD00F2 [Expansion Desktop Drive]
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2150 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046 Bluetooth Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed from backports-3.16-1

```
cd backports-3.16-1
sudo make uninstall
```

And reboot

Comment: Thanks, now I can choose what wireless card to use. Thanks a lot! :)