# How to install TP-LINK TL-WN722N on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, drivers, system-installation, system-settings

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to install my TL-WN722N. I'v seen several tutorials on how, but the don't seem to stick...

I've seen that it is supported by ubuntu, I "lsub" it and it does recognizes it, but I can't make the wireless work.

Could some one help me step by step on how to install it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here is one of the tutorials I used:
https://github.com/erickcion/tlwn722n-linux-install

Here is another:
[How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04)

this is what lsus repported:

```
ernesto@Ernesto:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

This is what i got after checking if the driver loads automatically:

```
ernesto@Ernesto:~$ lsmod | grep ath
ath9k_htc              75131  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              446521  2 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc
ath                    29006  3 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw
mac80211              652718  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              494362  4 ath,ath9k_common,mac80211,ath9k_htc
```

To check the wireless interface, this appears:

```
ernesto@Ernesto:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The message log for the wlan:

```
ernesto@Ernesto:~$ dmesg | grep -e wlan -e ath9k
[   10.648823] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
[   10.648931] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[   10.785561] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 11233
[   11.783282] ath9k_htc 1-3:1.0: ath9k_htc: Target is unresponsive
[   11.783296] ath9k_htc: Failed to initialize the device
[   11.786525] usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized  
[ 9320.372981] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
[ 9320.514042] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 11233
[ 9321.512915] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: Target is unresponsive
[ 9321.512929] ath9k_htc: Failed to initialize the device
[ 9321.515984] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
```

the last step didnt do anything:

```
rfkill list all
```

I checked for the size:

```
ernesto@Ernesto:~$ ls -al /lib/firmware/htc_9271.fw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11233 abr  7 23:03 /lib/firmware/htc_9271.fw
```

I reinstalled the firmwire, rebooted and checked the driver:

```
ernesto@Ernesto:~$ dmesg | grep ath9k
[   11.820232] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: Firmware htc_9271.fw requested
[   11.820469] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[   12.224275] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51272
[   12.462132] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[   12.739299] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.3
```

Comment: My TL-WN722N works with 3.2.0-23 and 3.2.0-74 without having to do anything more than enter the wifi password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a lot more information, it is impossible to propose a solution. After we have more details, I will edit this answer to add a solution.

Does the driver load automatically, as expected? Check:

```
lsmod | grep ath
```

If not, try to load it and see if there are any errors or warnings at the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
```

If it loads without complaint, check to see if a wireless interface, ideally *wlan0*, was created:

```
iwconfig
```

If no *wlan0* is created, see if the message log has any clues:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e ath9k
```

Finally, in some cases, the wireless switch for an internal device will prevent a USB wireless from working. Check to see if the switch is stopping the USB:

```
rfkill list all
```

I wonder if the firmware is corrupted. I notice:

> usb 1-3: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 11233

However, on my system, the size is different:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51272 Nov 24 10:42 /lib/firmware/htc_9271.fw
```

Please edit your question to add the result of:

```
ls -al /lib/firmware/htc_9271.fw
```

If it is not of the size 51272, let's reinstall the firmware package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Then reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep ath9k
```

With further details, we will proceed.

Comment: Did you reinstall the firmware as i suggested? The size appears incorrect.

Comment: i DID AND ITŚ WORKING NOW! tHANKS A LOT!! iTS WORKING JUST FINE NOW...

Comment: Just reinstall firmware worked for me as well!

Comment: apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware did it!! You are a life saver <3