# TP Link WN722N driver installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers

I am currently installing TP Link WN722N driver on my Ubuntu 16.04. My new laptop contains a RTL8822BE wireless device. There is no driver for Ubuntu meanwhile. Therefore I have to buy a wireless USB and wait for any update.

The installer is downloaded from https://github.com/ebirbe/tlwn722n-linux-install. However, there is an error during installation.

```
sudo bash install.sh

Installing firware...

Changing to directory "compat-drivers-source"...
Trying to select the ath9k_htc diver to be compiled...
Processing new driver-select request...
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/net/wireless/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/net/wireless/ath/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: net/wireless/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/ssb/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/bcma/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: drivers/misc/eeprom/Makefile.bk
Backup exists: Makefile.bk
Compiling modules...
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-24-generic/build M=/home/simon/Downloads/tlwn722n-linux-install-master/compat-drivers-source modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic'
/home/simon/Downloads/tlwn722n-linux-install-master/compat-drivers-source/config.mk:21: *** "ERROR: compat-drivers by default supports kernels >= 2.6.24, try enabling only one driver though".  Stop.
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/simon/Downloads/tlwn722n-linux-install-master/compat-drivers-source' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/simon/Downloads/tlwn722n-linux-install-master/compat-drivers-source] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic'
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
There was a problem compiling the package.
```

Is there any suggestion for a correct installation? I have tried to reinstall linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic but it did not work.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any comment or idea.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/836207/how-to-install-drivers-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-16-04

Comment: Have you bought the device yet? There are two versions. One, which has the `ath9k_htc` chipset, works out of the box with no driver install needed. The other chipset is an `8188eu`. Please see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/912498/tl-wn722n-is-not-recognized If you already have the device, please run: `lsusb` and edit your question to add the result. We can then identify the chipset.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Indeed it is related to chili555's post. It is now solved. Thanks anyway heynnema. I have tried that before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TL-WN722N is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912498/tl-wn722n-is-not-recognized)