# TP-Link TL-WN722N driver stopped working

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, ath9k

### Problem:

I have a TP-Link TL-WN722N external wireless card (basically an Atheros AR9271). It was working fine with my machine until today evening, where a power failure occured. On restarting, it does not work with the machine anymore. It does not show up on `ifconfig` or in the system tray (my machine only has an ethernet, and the WiFi option was completely absent).

In this question, Machine **A** refers to the problem machine: a Dell optiplex 3020 (ubuntu 16.04). Machine **B** is a test machine: a Dell optiplex 3040 (ubuntu 16.04) on which the adapter works without a hitch.

### Tried so far:

- Rebooted multiple times out of frustration. No change
- Tried different usb ports. No change.
- Saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607830/how-to-install-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu) thread, which provided some info on how to proceed with diagonostics (all of this is done on machine **A**)

  - `lsusb` registers the device (bus `003`, device `009`)

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 1949:0004 Lab126, Inc. Amazon Kindle 3/4/Paperwhite
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- `lsmod` lists `ath9k_htc` as a driver

```
ath9k_htc              77824  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              479232  2 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw
mac80211              741376  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              565248  4 ath,ath9k_common,mac80211,ath9k_htc
```

- loading the driver with `sudo modprobe ath9k_htc` gives an error, as reported by `dmesg`:

```
[  779.021924] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
[  779.021933] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[  779.021939] usb 3-4: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[  779.021944] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[  779.021948] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 12345
[  779.022695] usb 3-4: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[  779.304846] usb 3-4: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[  779.557139] ath9k_htc 3-4:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  885.709381] ath9k_htc: Failed to initialize the device
[  885.709604] usb 3-4: ath9k_htc: USB layer deinitialized
```

- **Control experiment: Testing if it is not a hardware problem**: I plugged the wifi module into machine **B** and it worked just fine. Here are some diagonostics from **B** using `dmesg`

```
[  204.816781] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[  204.816927] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[  205.110170] usb 1-2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[  205.362327] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  205.631164] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[  205.631167] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[  205.631169] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
[  205.631170] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  205.631171] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  205.631172] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[  205.631173] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[  205.631174] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[  205.644713] ath9k_htc 1-2:1.0 wlx60e32712cd74: renamed from wlan0
[  386.990035] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
```

- **Checked if drivers are not corrupted**: The machine loads the driver in `/lib/firmware/ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw`. I copied this file from machine **B** to **A** and ran a `diff` on them: both binaries are identical. As a double check, also compared `/lib/firmware/htc_9271.fw` on both machines with each other: they are also identical.
- **Final resort**: reinstalled drivers using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware`. This did not fix the problem.

I'm out of ideas. The drivers are installed and non-corrupted, yet loading the driver on **A** gives the non-verbose error `Failed to initialize the device`. This problem was also quite spontaneous and happened out of the blue: the adapter was working fine up until now. Any ideas for further diagonostics or a fix for this issue are appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a hardware failure.

Comment: @Pilot6 the control experiment on **B** verified that the wifi module works. Do you mean a hardware failure on machine **A**?

Comment: Show me `grep -i REGDOMAIN /etc/default/crda`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on these matters, however:

I had a similar issue (without the lightning) at about the same date with my usb TP-Link TL-WN722N. I was running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and module 4.4.0-186-generic. When I manually boot to 4.4.0-185-generic the TP-Link works fine. I hope this helps. Good luck.