# Airties 2315 Wireless USB adapter

Tags: wireless, usb, ath9k

I am new to Linux. I have Ubuntu MATE. 16.04 64 bit installed on my computer but I can't get my Airties 2315 usb wireless internet card to work. This is a known problem on the Turkish Linux Mint forums and they managed to fix it with ndiswrapper, a method that I can't get to work.

Instead, I plan to add this device to the Atheros driver list in Ubuntu. Judging by what I can tell from the Windows drivers, I know that the Airties 2315 uses Atheros AR9271. I also know from the Debian wiki that AR9271 is supported by the ath9k-htc module. I need to find a way to add the usb device below to the module (sorry for that I didn't use the command line format...)

lsusb:

```
ID 1eda:2315 AirTies Wireless Networks
```

usb-devices | awk '/1eda/' RS=

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1eda ProdID=2315 Rev=01.08
S:  Manufacturer=ATHEROS
S:  Product=USB2.0 WLAN
S:  SerialNumber=12345
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

I presume that my solution should be similar to the method below, but I need the your help to try it with the Airties device.

[How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04?newreg=945aba76d2374e1092654fbd32f252c6)

Thanks again!

EDIT output of iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx182861282acd  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TTNET_ZyXEL_UVWN"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 5C:F4:AB:DC:F3:D7   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:375   Missed beacon:0

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

EDIT to make changes permanent, screen of cat /etc/udev/rules.d/ath9k_htc.conf:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1eda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2315", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe ath9k_htc" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1eda 2315 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id'"

ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1eda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2315", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe ath9k_htc", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1eda 2315 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id'"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/1eda/' RS=` terminal command.

Comment: Please try the @chili555 answer. If it works, I will make a module and create an upstream patch. But it may need some additional steps, if it does not.

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe -r ath9k`. This will disable the internal wifi. If you can use the dongle, I will send a patch to kernel maintainers.

Comment: We need to see which one is connected.

Comment: Yes ran the command you mentioned. The internal wifi now says "device not managed". The internet is still working and my Airties device's green light is still on.

Comment: OK. Now you can use it with that command, and I adding support to the upstream kernel.

Comment: By the way, what command do I need to write to turn the internal wifi device back on?

Comment: `sudo modprobe ath9k` will turn it on. If it does not, just reboot.

Comment: And what command do I need to write to make sure the Airties USB will always work even after rebooting?

Comment: I will write an answer how to make it permanent.

Comment: One last thing, the modification of the module as stated by chili555 will eventually become the module for all ubuntu distributions, am I correct?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I will add it upstream, then it will get into Ubuntu stable kernels in a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a Google search, I am not at all persuaded that this is an `ath9k_htc` device. It is, however, easy to temporarily test it. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
echo "1eda 2315" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id
```

Did your wireless spring to life? Is a wireless interface created?

```
iwconfig
```

Are there any interesting clues in the log?

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

If you wish to disable your internal device, please do:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r ath9k
echo "blacklist ath9k"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: Yes, it sprang to life. The green led on it is working and I can connect to the internet. However, I am using it on a laptop with an internal wifi card that I cannot disable, that may change my results. Regardless, I think this solution worked.

Comment: Why can't you disable the built-in wifi? It is quite easy. We need to test if it really works. Can you post the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`. I will tell you how to disable the internal wifi. @Fah11277

Comment: Pilot6, I have done as you asked.

Comment: There is no need to permanently blacklist ath9k. It was only for testing to make sure the connection is through the dongle.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by the efforts of chili555 and Pilot6. The wireless card works perfectly now.

First,

```
sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
echo "1eda 2315" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id
```

must be entered. This makes sure that Ubuntu uses the ath9k_htc driver for the Airties 2315 device.

To ensure that Ubuntu will continue to use this driver even after reboot, I changed my `/etc/rc.local file` by using "sudo nano" command. I copy-pasted the commands used by chili555 . Those commands:

```
    sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
    echo "1eda 2315" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath9k_htc/new_id
```

have to be to added before the line `exit 0` of the rc.local file. There are no problems now. According to Pilot6, this problem will likely be fixed in the near future.