# make: *** [clean] Error 1

Tags: wireless, make, adapter

I am new to Ubuntu. I followed [How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set up wifi adapter.
When I execute `sudo make clean` I am getting following error

```
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Please give me some idea

Comment: What Ubuntu version (`cat /etc/lsb-release`) and kernel version (`uname -r`) do you actually have, and what version of the driver did you download, exactly?

Comment: backports-3.16 is far too old to build in any recent Ubuntu version. Moreover, the driver you are apparently wanting to build, `ath9k_htc` is included by default in all recent Ubuntu versions. If you plug in the device and it doesn't work, something else is wrong and building an antique driver isn't the solution. Please tell us what's not happening as expected.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.10