# Is there any way to install updates/drivers from USB?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, usb, lubuntu

So, I've been trying to get my wireless connection to work most of today. The only solutions I can find tell me to download various drivers or updates, usually as a first step. Some guides even tell me to wget scripts just for the diagnostics step.

This is not possible. I cannot connect via. ethernet to my router, as it is upstairs at the back of the house and the PC in question is downstairs at the front.

Is there some way I can find and download updates on my main PC, and transfer them via. USB to Lubuntu?

Is there somewhere I can find and then download and install the ath9k driver from a USB? (I am given to understand that it should come with the distro, but it certainly doesn't in Lubuntu 16.04).

Is there somewhere I can find and install NdisWrapper? I can't run the make commands in Lubuntu, as the "make" package is missing from Lubuntu, so I'd need a way to install the make package as well.

Asking in roughly the order of my preference.

**EDIT:**

Results of running partial commands below:

*sudo lshw -C network*

```
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: enp0s25
   version: 02
   serial: 00:21:70:1d:6f:56
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.4-0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:25 memory:fe9e0000-fe9fffff memory:fe9db000-fe9dbfff ioport:ecc0(size=32)
```

*lspci -vnn*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express DRAM Controller [8086:29b0] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29b2] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
I/O ports at ec90 [size=8]
Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at feb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29b3] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Memory at fea80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:03.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express MEI Controller [8086:29b4] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
Memory at f0200800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me

00:03.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express PT IDER Controller [8086:29b6] (rev 02) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
I/O ports at fe80 [size=8]
I/O ports at fe90 [size=4]
I/O ports at fea0 [size=8]
I/O ports at feb0 [size=4]
I/O ports at fef0 [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ata_generic
Kernel modules: pata_acpi

00:03.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Serial KT Controller [8086:29b7] (rev 02) (prog-if 02 [16550])
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
I/O ports at ec98 [size=8]
Memory at fe9da000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: serial

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10bd] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell OptiPlex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
Memory at fe9e0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Memory at fe9db000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
I/O ports at ecc0 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
I/O ports at ff20 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
I/O ports at ff00 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
Memory at fe9d9c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
Memory at fe9dc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
Memory behind bridge: fe800000-fe8fffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f01fffff
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
I/O ports at ff80 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
I/O ports at ff60 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
I/O ports at ff40 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at ff980800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev 92) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=32
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801IO (ICH9DO) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2914] (rev 02)
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2922] (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Dell 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1028:0211]
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
I/O ports at fe00 [size=8]
I/O ports at fe10 [size=4]
I/O ports at fe20 [size=8]
I/O ports at fe30 [size=4]
I/O ports at fec0 [size=32]
Memory at f0200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell Optiplex 755 [1028:0211]
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 9
Memory at fe9d9b00 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at ece0 [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
```

Sorry, I was a bit confused by the results when I ran those commands piped into grep (? or the other way around), so I thought I'd share the full results. 02.0 seems to be something to do with integrated graphics?

In case it helps, my wireless card is the TL-WN722N USB, not a PCI-E slot (although I have a PCI-E card I could try using, due to the nature of the Dell Optiplex 755 case I'd need to take a coping saw to the case to allow it to fit).

*lsusb*

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:010c
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0002 China Resource Smico., Ltd
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

*lspci -nnk | grep 280 -A2*

```
blank/null result
```

Comment: Before trying *any* of those things, I'd suggest running `lspci -vnn | grep '\[02.0\]'` and/or `sudo lshw -C network | grep 'product:\|configuration:'` and adding the result(s) to your question so we can confirm the best route

Comment: I've had a go, is that better?

Comment: Thanks (and apologies - I didn't notice you'd said it was a USB device - so asking for `lspci` output was probably not very useful)

Comment: Not your fault! I didn't say it was a USB device actually, only that I wanted to install some helpful packages/drivers from USB, if that was possible without `make`. I wasn't 100% sure if lspci even checked PCI-E slots, that was a guess.

Comment: With the device inserted, please run and post: `lsusb` ndiswrapper is almost *never* helpful.

Comment: Probable reference: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v2

Comment: Added `lsusb` output, it doesn't seem to look anything like the reference lsusb output, do I need to add another command to get more detail?

Comment: Your device is *exactly* the reference usb.id: 2357:010c. It requires the r8188eu driver which is present by default in Ubuntu 17.04 but must be compiled for earlier versions. Unless you wish to reinstall 17.04, I will propose an answer as to how to proceed by transferring the driver by USB. Which is your preference?

Comment: Probable reference if on-line: https://askubuntu.com/questions/912498/tl-wn722n-is-not-recognized/912507#912507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please download these files on some other computer and transfer them to the desktop of the Lubuntu machine with a USB key or similar:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/archive/master.zip

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb

Now, on the desktop of the Lubuntu machine, install *dkms*:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
```

If it complains that there are missing dependencies, tell us what they are so we may download a few more packages to satisfy those missing. The missing packages will be found here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dkms Please be certain to select 32-bit (i386) or 64-bit (amd64) as needed for your machine. Confirm:

```
arch
```

32-bit returns i686 and 64 bit is x86_64.

Please see @JimmyM's very helpful list below for a complete list.

Next, do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
unzip master.zip
sudo mv rtl8188eu  /usr/src
cd /usr/src
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: That's incredible, thank you so much. I will try this as soon as I get back, as I have to pop out now. Thank you for all your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Alright, I've tried to do this for quite a while now and can't get around this problem - I can't install gcc, because its dependencies include itself!

Comment: I believe gcc depends on gcc-5 and cpp. Please check here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize gcc-5 was a different program, as the gcc version I downoaded was version 5.x I assumed that referred to the current gcc install. Thank you again! I would of course upvote you if I had the ability.

Comment: You will probably have to install all three in one command; e.g. `sudo dpkg -i gcc-*.deb gcc-5-*.deb cpp-*.deb`

Comment: You probably also need cpp-5.

Comment: I've needed a whole lot more than that! Would it be useful to provide the full list of files needed for this case so that you can edit them into your answer, or is it too case-dependent to be particularly handy?

Comment: It would be very helpful. Do you have the list? Related: http://lubuntuhowto.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-install-cc-compiler-on-lubuntu-1604.html

Comment: Yeap, it's on my USB stick. I'll get it for you when I run downstairs again, in the mean-time `sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu` has failed, it says no such Directory `/usr/src/-.rtl8188eu`, the problem's quite hard to Google due to the punctuation so any pointers would be appreciated! I'll be right back with the full list of dependencies.

Comment: Here goes, unfortunately the order of install got scrambled:

`lipdpkg-perl_1.18.4    libstdc++-5-dev_5.4.0    lspcivnn    build-essential_12.1    dpkg-dev_1.18.4    gcc_5.3.1    gcc-5_5.4.0    make_4.1-6    binutils_2.26.1    gcc-6-base_6.0.1    libc6_2.23-0    libgcc1_6.0.1-0    libcc1-0_5.4.0-6    libgcc-5-dev_5.4.0-6    libasan2_5.4.0-6    libatomic1_5.4.0-6    libcilkrts5_5.4.0-6    libitm1_5.4.0-6    libmpx0_5.4.0-6    libubsan0_5.4.0-6    g++_5.3.1-1    libc6-dev_2.23-0      g++-5_5.4.0-6    libc6_2.23-0    libc-dev-bin_2.23-0    linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-79.100`

Comment: If you need that reformatted before it can be used let me know, was a struggle fitting it into the comment box

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes. I am sorry that I missed a critical step.

Comment: No problem! I'm very grateful that you've taken the time to help me for free.

Comment: I missed the `cd /usr/src` step. Sorry. Please try again. I'll stand by.

Comment: It's worked! The card now shows up in `sudo lshw -C network`, albeit in a disabled state (but I'll work out a way around that. Thank you!