# GCC won't install from USB in Lubuntu because it requires GCC as a dependency?

Tags: usb, package-management, lubuntu, compiling, gcc

So, GCC is a missing dependency of dkms*.deb. That's fine, I assume, I try to download GCC along with the few other dependent dependencies I need, and install it.

But in order to install GCC, it says that I need GCC already installed as a dependency! What the hell?

Surely without GCC, for one, Lubuntu wouldn't even work.

Anyway, is there any way to kind of bootstrap-install(? terminology) GCC please? Or to diagnose why Lubuntu isn't recognizing the presumably existent GCC install?

edit: trying to use `sudo dpkg -i gcc*.deb` to install, if that helps, extrapolating from commands [kindly provided here](https://askubuntu.com/a/924363/699169).

Comment: I *think* gcc is installed by default - if you open a terminal and enter `gcc -v`, what is the result?

Comment: You're correct - naturally `gcc-5` and `gcc_5`, i.e. version 5 are different. Obvious to anyone with experience of Linux, rather strange and arcane to me!

Comment: We were all beginners, even me and even Linus Torvalds, once upon a time. Keep going!