# Install Wireless Driver TP-LINK TL-WN781ND

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I've just moved from windows to ubuntu, so I'm new in ubuntu, I tried to install ubuntu 16.04.2 and it's running normally, but no wireless is detected, I tried to find the driver like on this thread:

[How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04)

But there will always be an error as in

[TL-WN722N is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912498/tl-wn722n-is-not-recognized)

I tried all the tips but wireless still does not show up.

I'm using TP-LINK TL-WN781ND on Ubuntu 16.04.2.

this is my `lsusb` :

`Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04d9:a070 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2717:ff80 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

this my `lshw -class network` :

`*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 16
       serial: b8:97:5a:eb:06:2b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:240 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fd604000-fd604fff memory:fd600000-fd603fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fd500000-fd57ffff memory:fd580000-fd58ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp1s0f0u12
       serial: 22:a9:a4:2a:94:09
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.23 link=yes multicast=yes`

this is my `lspci | grep Network` :

`0a:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`

this my `sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath`:

`[    4.936564]  [<ffffffffa5a831ef>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
[    8.183789] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x21
[    8.183790] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    8.183791] ath: Country alpha2 being used: AU
[    8.183792] ath: Regpair used: 0x21
[    8.183833] ath: phy0: dma_mapping_error() on RX init
[    8.183862] ath9k 0000:0a:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[    8.183955] ath9k: probe of 0000:0a:00.0 failed with error -12`

Can someone help me, please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the Ubuntu release you're running. Also please identify your device using `lsusb`. According to https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN781ND_v1 there are two versions but both should have Atheros chipsets supported by `ath9k` driver, included and working in any recent Ubuntu release. Neither links you posted are relevant for TL-WN781ND.

Comment: Thank you. And your Ubuntu release/version is...? It does appear unclaimed indeed where `ath9k` should be.

Comment: my ubuntu is ubuntu 16.04.2, so, what should i do?, i'm new in ubuntu. sorry.

Comment: Start by disabling Secure Boot at UEFI. If the driver isn't signed (most likely) secure boot will prevent it from loading.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath

Comment: i already edit it @chili555, thank you

Comment: @chili555 Found references to "error -5" at OpenWRT fora, but not to "error -12". Anyway, my feeling about secure boot was wrong, apparently.

Comment: @MichaelBay my secure boot already disable from the beginning,