# How to install a TP-LINK TL-WN722N driver with 4.13 kernel version

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, tp-link

I would really appreciate your help. Im trying to install driver for the device mentioned above. I installed the firmware and the messages from *iwconfig* looks that way:

```
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u2  no wireless extensions.

wlxc025e9198290  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

So the system recognizes the device and it shows the drivers i think:

```
lsmod | grep ath
ath9k_htc              77824  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              462848  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              610304  5 ath9k_htc,mac80211,r8188eu,ath,ath9k_common
```

So i will really appreciate any help with installing this device. And the kernel version is 4.13.0-16-generic. The system is Ubuntu 17.10. Thanks guys.

edit: If it would help i followed this guide https://askubuntu.com/a/912507/761970

/UPDATE/

It scans:

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlxc025e9198290  Scan completed :
  Cell 01 - Address: 64:70:02:CA:95:B2
            ESSID:"Salaga"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
            Extra:wpa_ie=dd160050f20101000050f20401000050f20401000050f202
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : CCMP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : CCMP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            IE: Unknown: DD3F0050F204104A00011010440001021047001000000000000010000000647002CA9510103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001
            Quality=0/100  Signal level=70/100  
  Cell 02 - Address: D4:6E:0E:93:B2:16
            ESSID:"TP-Link"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
            Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac04000fac020100000fac020000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            IE: Unknown: DD260050F204104A0001101044000102104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001
            Quality=0/100  Signal level=59/100  
  Cell 03 - Address: C0:4A:00:46:96:AC
            ESSID:"SSPL"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
            Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : CCMP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
            Quality=0/100  Signal level=43/100  
  Cell 04 - Address: 5C:8A:38:DD:BA:50
            ESSID:"eduroam"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:on
            Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
            Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac010000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : CCMP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            Quality=0/100  Signal level=84/100  
  Cell 05 - Address: 5C:8A:38:DD:BA:51
            ESSID:"Hotspot PL"
            Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
            Mode:Master
            Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
            Encryption key:off
            Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
            Quality=0/100  Signal level=92/100  

enp0s20f0u2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

dmesg show this:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlx -e ath
[    6.664353] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlxc025e9198290: renamed from wlan0
[   14.179691] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc025e9198290: link is not ready
[   14.657553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc025e9198290: link is not ready
[   15.258315] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxc025e9198290: link is not ready
```

In the network manager i only see loopback and nothing more. Thanks for response @chili555 . I really appreciate your help :)

/UPDATE2/

So the version is written on the device and it's V2. Results:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 22b8:2e25 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

/UPDATE3/

So i did what u asked me to do and here are the results: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26014129/

Comment: It looks like it's working perfectly well! Does it scan? From the terminal: `sudo iwlist scan` Are there any interesting messages in the log? `dmesg | grep -e wlx -e ath` Do you see networks when you click the Network Manager icon? Does it try to connect?

Comment: @chili555 so it works, because it scans but i can't see the device in network manager :/

Comment: i think the problem is that when i write `sudo modprobe 8188eu` i get:
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8188eu': Device or resource busy

Comment: Let's determine if it is the V1 using the Atheros chipset or the V2 using the Realtek chipset. Please *edit your question* to include the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`.

Comment: So u think that the problem is that i installed 2 drivers and the one is wrong, right?

Comment: Yes, and a few other things!!

Answer (score 0):

The driver `r8188eu` exists by default in kernel version 4.13; there is no need to install anything else. Let's correct the previous steps:

```
sudo dkms uninstall 8188eu/1.0 --all
```

Next, I do not know how the incorrect driver for the V1 device, `ath9k_htc` got loaded. Do you have a declaration in /etc/modules? If so, please remove it.

Next, let's check Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Be certain that the file now reads:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

After making any needed changes, save the file (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit nano (Ctrl+x).

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: So i uninstalled the driver, but couldn't do it with --all parameter, it gave me an error but uninstalled without the option. Next i checked /etc/modules-load.d/ and in the modules.conf there is no line with the ath9k_htc driver. I checked NetworkManager.conf and the file contains the same text as the above. Still no improvements, it scans from terminal but is not visible in network manager. Thanks @chili555

Comment: I chcecked /etc/modules and there is no line with the wrong driver included

Comment: In order to better diagnose what is going on ( or wrong!) with Network Manager, please provide the diagnostics as here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: So i did what u asked for :D

Comment: May we see the link to the results?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26014129/ 
I have pasted that 2 days ago though, look up.

Comment: Your wireless script results look just perfect. Does the Network Manager icon not appear at the top right? If it appears, when you click it, do you not see your network or any networks at all? If it does not appear, can you get it to show with a terminal command: `sudo nm-applet &` http://www.cs.mun.ca/~donald/linux-mun-wireless/latest/images/00-network-manager.png

Comment: Okay, so i'm dumb and all i had to do was open the damn widget. What a shame. It just worked. Thanks man for all your time, it's only ma fault. Have a great day.

Comment: I'm glad it's working by whatever means. Have fun!