# Default wifi adapter not detected after settings for tp-link adapter

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, laptop

I use ubuntu 16.04 LTS
I'm trying install tp-link wn722n according to 
[How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04)

After then settings my defaulf laptop wifi adapter was not detected.
And tp-link adapter not works also

System info(with removed tp-link adapter):

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-83-generic

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7054 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2717:ff80  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

rfkill shows only Bluetooth

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers 
(rev 08)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated 
Graphics (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I try this for recovery:

```
sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl*
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer bcmwl*
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer bcmwl*
```

And this:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get remove firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

I'm not understand how to recover my default wifi adapter laptop driver.

Additional info - 
`modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` output

```
[   13.771761] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   13.944729] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.089900] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.885177] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_session
[   14.885180] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_session (err -22)
[   14.885186] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_gtk_rekey_notify
[   14.885187] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_gtk_rekey_notify (err -22)
[   14.885216] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
[   14.885217] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
[   14.885223] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_connection_loss
[   14.885225] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_connection_loss (err -22)
[   14.885229] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_report_wowlan_wakeup
[   14.885230] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -22)
[   14.885238] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_interfaces
[   14.885239] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_interfaces (err -22)
[   14.885243] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_stopped
[   14.885244] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_stopped (err -22)
[   14.885249] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_chswitch_done
[   14.885251] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_chswitch_done (err -22)
[   14.885265] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unreserve_tid
[   14.885266] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unreserve_tid (err -22)
[   14.885285] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_hw
[   14.885286] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_hw (err -22)
[   14.885294] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_tkip_p2k
[   14.885295] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_tkip_p2k (err -22)
[   14.885298] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_stations_atomic
[   14.885299] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_stations_atomic (err -22)
[   14.885306] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_session
[   14.885307] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_start_tx_ba_session (err -22)
[   14.885312] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_loss
[   14.885313] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_loss (err -22)
[   14.885325] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_register_hw
[   14.885326] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_register_hw (err -22)
[   14.885331] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_restart_hw
[   14.885332] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_restart_hw (err -22)
[   14.885336] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sta_eosp
[   14.885337] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sta_eosp (err -22)
[   14.885341] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rate_control_unregister
[   14.885342] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rate_control_unregister (err -22)
[   14.885346] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name
[   14.885347] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name (err -22)
[   14.885365] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queue
[   14.885366] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queue (err -22)
[   14.885391] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_find_sta
[   14.885392] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_find_sta (err -22)
[   14.885395] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iter_keys
[   14.885396] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iter_keys (err -22)
[   14.885408] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sta_set_buffered
[   14.885410] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sta_set_buffered (err -22)
[   14.885419] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state
[   14.885421] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state (err -22)
[   14.885445] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe
[   14.885446] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_tx_ba_cb_irqsafe (err -22)
[   14.885452] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw
[   14.885453] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw (err -22)
[   14.885459] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_gtk_rekey_add
[   14.885460] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_gtk_rekey_add (err -22)
[   14.885468] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol regulatory_set_wiphy_regd_sync_rtnl
[   14.885469] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol regulatory_set_wiphy_regd_sync_rtnl (err -22)
[   14.885476] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_reserve_tid
[   14.885477] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_reserve_tid (err -22)
[   14.885482] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_find_sta_by_ifaddr
[   14.885484] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_find_sta_by_ifaddr (err -22)
[   14.885486] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sta_block_awake
[   14.885487] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sta_block_awake (err -22)
[   14.885491] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_remain_on_channel_expired
[   14.885492] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -22)
[   14.885512] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queues
[   14.885513] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queues (err -22)
[   14.885517] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_template
[   14.885518] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_template (err -22)
[   14.885520] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rate_control_register
[   14.885521] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rate_control_register (err -22)
[   14.885528] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_txskb
[   14.885529] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_txskb (err -22)
[   14.885534] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw_nm
[   14.885535] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw_nm (err -22)
[   14.885554] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tx_status
[   14.885555] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status (err -22)
[   14.885561] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queue
[   14.885562] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queue (err -22)
[   14.885565] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_ready_on_channel
[   14.885566] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ready_on_channel (err -22)
[   14.885569] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queues
[   14.885570] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queues (err -22)
[   14.885583] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_results
[   14.885584] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_sched_scan_results (err -22)
[   14.885590] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023
[   14.885591] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_data_to_8023 (err -22)
[   14.885593] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_scan_completed
[   14.885594] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_scan_completed (err -22)
[   14.885597] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_atomic
[   14.885598] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_atomic (err -22)
[   14.885604] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol rate_control_send_low
[   14.885605] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol rate_control_send_low (err -22)
[   14.885616] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
[   14.885617] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
[   14.885620] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect
[   14.885621] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_resume_disconnect (err -22)
[   14.885629] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_csa_update_counter
[   14.885630] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_csa_update_counter (err -22)
[   14.885660] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tdls_oper_request
[   14.885661] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tdls_oper_request (err -22)
[   14.885663] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_cqm_rssi_notify
[   14.885664] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err -22)
[   14.885671] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_request_smps
[   14.885672] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_request_smps (err -22)
[   14.885674] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_csa_is_complete
[   14.885675] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_csa_is_complete (err -22)
[   14.885689] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol regulatory_set_wiphy_regd
[   14.885690] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol regulatory_set_wiphy_regd (err -22)
[   14.885692] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_rtnl
[   14.885694] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_rtnl (err -22)
[   14.885714] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_csa_finish
[   14.885715] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_csa_finish (err -22)
[   14.885720] iwlmvm: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rx_napi
[   14.885721] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx_napi (err -22)
[   14.900546] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to load module iwlmvm (error 256), is dynamic loading enabled?
```

Comment: It looks that you don't know what are you doing. Why do you install or uninstall Broadcom wireless drivers? It is not related at all. You don't have a Broadcom device. You also have a built in Intel adapter. Why don't just use it?

Comment: What did you do from the referred answer? Installed old backports? That was a very bad idea. It is not easy to recover. The fastest way is to re-install the system.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i'm ready for going to hard way, but please, don't say "reinstall system", this is not unix way