# Is this W-LAN repeater-modem supported by Ubuntu too?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

here is a W-LAN Repeater Modem with USB - and Ethernet - Ports.

Modell is a TP-LINK tl-wr710n.

I found here a howto setup drivers for Modell tl-wn722n.

[How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512727/how-to-install-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn722n-on-ubuntu-14-04#512859)

Would this work too for tl-wr710n ?!

Answer (score 2):

First, the TP‑LINK TL‑WR710N is a wireless router, not a wireless adapter. Second, the answer you linked is the process to install a driver in an Ubuntu computer to drive the TP-LINK adapter. I doubt that the router is running Ubuntu.

Next, I suspect that they are using entirely different chipsets.

The router should work out of the box with no need at all to install drivers.

Comment: Thanks for enlightenment - I have slept over the phases of W-LAN progress in general ...